# get the lowest and highest most popular hue color from an image

Tags: c#, image-processing, histogram, emgucv

I have an image and I want to find the most dominant lowest hue colour and the most dominant highest hue colour from an image.

It is possible that there are several colours/hues that are close to each other in populace to be dominant and if that is the case I would need to take an average of the most popular.

I am using emgu framework here.

I load an image into the HSV colour space.

I split the hue channel away from the main image.

I then use the DenseHistogram to return my ranges of 'buckets'.

Now, I could enumerate through the bin collection to get what I want but I am mindful of conserving memory when and wherever I can.

So, is there a way of getting what I need at all from the DenseHistogram 'object'?

i have tried MinMax (as shown below) and I have consider using linq but not sure if that is expensive to use and/or how to use it with just using a float array.

This is my code so far:

```
            float[] GrayHist;

            Image<Hsv, Byte> hsvSample = new Image<Hsv, byte>("An image file somewhere");
            DenseHistogram Histo = new DenseHistogram(255, new RangeF(0, 255));
            Histo.Calculate(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { hsvSample[0] }, true, null);
            GrayHist = new float[256];
            Histo.MatND.ManagedArray.CopyTo(GrayHist, 0);
            float mins;
            float maxs;
            int[] minVals;
            int[] maxVals;

            Histo.MinMax(out mins, out maxs, out minVals, out maxVals); //only gets lowest and highest and not most popular
            List<float> ranges= GrayHist.ToList().OrderBy( //not sure what to put here..
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, premature optimization is the root of all evil. You should first solve your problem to the most satisfactory level you can/expect then address optimization. Remember that optimization kills readability so unless you exactly know what you're doing it is not advised to optimize prematurely. Beside that I don't think your actual concern should be much a problem (enumeration).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your telling me of your advice and experience. It is well worth noting and I thank you for it.  I am about to try out aforge contrast stretching. It is not as 'brutal' as equalhist as it is using a linear approach. I have tried it on a few images and the quality looks better. So I shall run this for 24hrs and look at the results tomorrow. Apart from all that I would need to see if it affects the RAM when running.  Many thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I can't directly help you in regards to using EMGUCV or AForge because I don't know them; one thing though : if you are concerned with memory usage you should adopt the `using` pattern (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). There are certainly objects in this API that implements `IDiposable` so it is advised to encompass them in `using`. The `using` pattern ensures that resources are disposed when the program exits that scope, and while making sure unneeded stuff is freed when done you will also gain a lot in clarity.

Comment: absolutely, many thanks